# Set second slider value of JQuery UI based on first slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two sliders. I am trying to change the second slider values based on the first slider change. I am not sure if I should use an if condition. There are set of values which I want to implement. For example, if the first slider values are

$6000.00, $6500.00, $7000.00, $7500.00, $8000.00, $8500.00, $9000.00, $9500.00, $10000.00

and second slider values are -

$411000.00, $416500.00, $421000.00, $426500.00, $431000.00, $436000.00, $441000.00, $446000.00, $450500.00

If first slider range is selected or set as $6000.00, then second slider should change to $411000.00 and if first slider is set to $6500.00, then second slider should be set to $416500.00 and likewise.

The code I am trying is-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(function() {
    $("#slider1").slider({
    value: 6000,
    min: 6000,
    max: 20000,
    step: 500,
   slide: function(event, ui) {
     $("#slider1-value").val(ui.value);
     $("#slider2").slider("option", "max", ui.value * 1.5);
     var max = $("#slider2").slider("option", "max");
     $("#slider2-max").val(max);
   }
   });
   
   $("#slider2").slider({
   value: 411000,
   min: 411000,
   max: 544000,
   slide: function(event, ui) {
     $("#slider2-value").val(ui.value);
   }
   });
   
     $("#slider1-value").val($('#slider1').slider('value'));
     $("#slider2-value").val($('#slider2').slider('value'));
   });
</script>

<div class="sliders-div">
   <label for="deposit-amount">Deposit Amount:</label>
   <input type="text" id="slider1-value" readonly>
   <div id="slider1"></div>
   <label for="package-price">Package Price:</label>
   <input type="text" id="slider2-max" readonly>
   <div id="slider2"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the max value in the option and the value of the slider, but the min value of the slider 2 remains the same at 411000 which is higher than your max value.

The following snippet is a working example, however the calculation of using the slider 1 value * 1.5 is not equal to the max value you want to set for slider 2. So I suggest you revise the calculation and make sure that when you change the option, the min and max value of the slider make sense.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider1").slider({
    value: 6000,
    min: 6000,
    max: 20000,
    step: 500,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#slider1-value").val(ui.value);
      $("#slider2").slider("option", "min", ui.value);
      $("#slider2").slider("option", "max", ui.value * 1.5);
      var max = $("#slider2").slider("option", "max");
      $("#slider2-max").val(max);
    }
  });
   
   $("#slider2").slider({
     value: 411000,
     min: 411000,
     max: 544000,
     slide: function(event, ui) {
       $("#slider2-value").val(ui.value);
     }
   });
   
   $("#slider1-value").val($('#slider1').slider('value'));
   $("#slider2-value").val($('#slider2').slider('value'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sliders-div">
   <label for="deposit-amount">Deposit Amount:</label>
   <input type="text" id="slider1-value" readonly>
   <div id="slider1"></div>
   <label for="package-price">Package Price:</label>
   <input type="text" id="slider2-value" readonly>
   <input type="text" id="slider2-max" readonly>
   <div id="slider2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mylee. Is there any way I can use if condition to set the values? Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean by using if condition to set the values. I don't see a reason to not be able to do that. You'll have to explain better what problem are you facing.

Comment: This is wah ti am talking about - If first slider range is selected or set as $6000.00, then second slider should change to $411000.00 and if first slider is set to $6500.00, then second slider should be set to $416500.00 and likewise. I can't do this with formula, because the ranges are not constant. I need to manually set the ranges. Thanks.

Comment: In other words, consider I have two different range sliders. If first slider value is set to A, then I want second slider value set to be B. Make sense in any way?